# Strange formatting in iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, ios-app

When posting a comment, why is "Chris's question" formatted like a link? It doesn't seem to be one - seems inconsistent with everything else.

[image]

Comment: Yeah that's strange. My first thought was maybe it is a link. What if we went the other way and made that link scroll you back to the post you're commenting on? In case you scrolled away to refer to something else, you could find it again.

Comment: That was what I was expecting it to do tbh. I wouldn't fussed if it was that, or removed though.

Comment: I was just thinking about that. A link would actually be pretty useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed in the next build.

I have no idea why we formatted it like a link when it doesn't do anything, but I'm making it do something now.  Tapping "Chris's question" will scroll you up to the question.  Similarly, I'll now show "Editing Chris's comment" when you edit a comment and tapping that will scroll you to the comment:

[image: Screenshot of editing a comment, showing the new title.]

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for not just taking the easy way out and changing the styling. One small gripe: "Editing Chris's comment" seems a little awkward since the comment will always be yourself (unless you're a moderator I take it?)

Comment: Cheers for both these fixes, @Brian!

Comment: @mhlester Excellent point.  For your own things I'll show "On your question/answer" and "Editing your comment".